# How to use ngModel of a model and allow additonally selection and input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a model Row:

```
export class Row {
    rowNumber: number;
    gender: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    emailAddress: string;
}
```

which I show in my template row.component.html like this:

```
<div class="form-group row col-md-6 ">
    <label for="gender " class="col-sm-6 col-form-label ">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <input id="gender" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="row.gender" />
    </div>
 </div> ...
```

Now the user is allowed to change the model. He can change the model by typing something in the input field (which is here possible)
Another option should be given by a selction. If the user clicks in the input field he should be able to select a option.

```
(click)="getSelection('gender')"
(click)="getSelection('jobRole')"
```

row.component.ts:

```
getSelection(field:string){
...
return list; 
}
```

How is this possible? The ngModel should be the row.gender. How can I assign the values to ngModel here?

For the selection I can use a modal, but the problem will still be the assignment.

thx in advance

Comment: Could you please create a plunker, I'm having a bit of trouble of understanding what should happen here, or rather trying to guess how the rest of the code looks like, so it would be nice to have a Plunker to tinker with :)